# About Wordpress and Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

> Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed; If you would like to pass argument by reference, modify the declaration of apply_filters(). in C:\xampp\htdocs\sociallocal\wp-content\plugins\buddypress\bp-core.php on line 565

How do I fix this?

This is the code with the error:

```
return apply_filters( 'bp_core_get_users', BP_Core_User::get_users( $type, $per_page, $page, $user_id, $include, $search_terms, $populate_extras ), &$params );
```

}

It looks good to me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try updating to the latest version of Buddypress?  V. 4.4.0

You must be using a very old version or a very customized version because this file does not exist:  `...plugins\buddypress\bp-core.php`